# Problems with Python Dictionarys and nested Lists

Tags: python

I am trying to create a dictionary that has a nested list inside of it.

The goal would be to have it be:

```
key : [x,y,z]
```

I am pulling the information from a csv file and counting the number of times a certain key shows up in each column. However I am getting the below error

```
> d[key][i] = 1
KeyError: 'owner'
```

Where owner is the title of my column.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = {}
    with open ('sample.csv','r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for i in range(0,3):
            for row in reader:
                key = row[0]
                if key in d:
                    d[key][i] +=1
                else:
                    d[key][i] = 1

    for key,value in d.iteritems():
        print key,value
```

What do I tweak in this loop to have it create a key if it doesn't exist and then add to it if it does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that you try to use a list (`[i]`) where no list is.

So you have to replace

```
d[key][i] = 1
```

with

```
d[key] = [0,0,0]
d[key][i] = 1
```

This would first create the list with three entries (so you can use `[0]`, `[1]` and `[2]` afterward without error) and then assigns one to the correct entry in the list.

Comment: This solved the error problem, so i accepted it, however my loop is not adding to any member of the array outside of the first

Comment: @Alex That is because you have to replace this: `d[key][i] = 1` with this `d[key][i] += 1`

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly. But you have one outer loop (for i in range(0,3):`) with sets `i` first to 0, then 1 and then 2. The inner loop iterates over the rows and adds the uses the first entry of that row to add one the list indicated by itself (`key`), but there in the entry indicated by `i`. Because that is all a bit complex, _I think you should carefully go through your code an check if you don't need to change the order of the loops or even remove the outer one._ Please write if I have misunderstood your code or your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

ncols = 3
d = defaultdict(lambda: [0 for i in range(ncols)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a try, catch block to append a list to the new key, then increment as needed

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = {}
    with open ('sample.csv','r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for i in xrange(0,3):
            for row in reader:
                key = row[i]
                try: d[key][i] += 1
                except KeyError:
                    d[key] = [0, 0, 0]
                    d[key][i] = 1

    for key,value in d.iteritems():
        print key,value
```

Answer (score 0):

Using defaultdict and Counter you can come up with a dict that allows you to easily measure how many times a key appeared in a position (in this case 1st, 2nd or 3rd, by the slice)

```
csv = [
    ['a','b','c','d'],
    ['e','f','g', 4 ],
    ['a','b','c','d']
]

from collections import Counter, defaultdict

d = defaultdict(Counter)

for row in csv:
    for idx, value in enumerate(row[0:3]):
        d[value][idx] += 1
```

example usage:

```
print d
print d['a'][0] #number of times 'a' has been found in the 1st position
print d['b'][2] #number of times 'b' found in the 3rd position
print d['f'][1] #number of times 'f' found in 2nd position
print [d['a'][n] for n in xrange(3)] # to match the format requested in your post

defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'a': Counter({0: 2}), 'c': Counter({2: 2}), 'b': Counter({1: 2}), 'e': Counter({0: 1}), 'g': Counter({2: 1}), 'f': Counter({1: 1})})
2
0
1
[2, 0, 0]
```

Or put into a function:

```
def occurrences(key):
    return [d[key][n] for n in xrange(3)]

print occurrences('a') # [2, 0, 0]
```